# .NET producer pattern with backpressure

Tags: .net, multithreading

I am looking for something that I can use to manage a worker pool. Each worker produces items. Items get queued up to be worked. However, the work queue can only process items so fast. I'd like something that increases the number of workers when there is excess capacity in the pool, and reduces it when the capacity drops.

I mean, I know how to write this myself. But I'd rather rely on some library already written.

I've looked at TPL dataflow: it has no backpressure.
I've looked at Reactive Extensions: they don't either (they do for Java).

So yeah, just looking for a library that already does it smoothly.

Comment: Please be more specific and technical in your question. What is a "worker", exactly? Is it a thread? A TPL `Task<T>`? A child process? A VM?

Comment: Are you shure to create far more threads than CPU's available when the workload increases? Doesn't sound verygood for me. Why isn't a threadpool who works on a queue not sufficient?

Comment: The functionality you're looking for, already exists inside the TPL. The TPL `TaskScheduler` implementations (e.g. `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`) provide way to queue and distribute load against the thread pool (which is able to do work stealing in order to improve fairness) in way to maximize the execution throughput.

Comment: I'm trying to deal with the producer side, not the consumer.